# $\int_a^bf(x)dx\neq0$ but $\int_a^bf(x)g^n(x)dx=0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Does there exist real-valued and continuous functions $f$ and $g$ defined on some interval $[a,b]\subset\mathbb{R}$ such that 
$$\int_a^bf(x)dx\neq0$$
but 
$$\int_a^bf(x)g^n(x)dx=0$$
for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}$?

Comment: Take $g \equiv 0$

Comment: What if $g$ is a constant function, and $\int_a^b f = 0$?

Comment: If we take $g \equiv 0$ then how do we define $g^n$ for $n<0$?

Comment: We want $\int_a^bf\neq0$

Comment: I have not read carefully. Ok

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As is, the answer is no. The precise condition is “the integral vanishes for every $n > 0$ and $g$ has no root”.

Indeed, according to the problem statement, $g$ must not vanish, so the image of $g$ is some compact interval $K$ not containing $0$. Then $x \in K \longmapsto 1/x$ is a continuous function on $K$, so there exists a sequence $p_n$ of polynomial functions on $K$ converging uniformly to $1/x$. Then $gp_n \circ g$ converges uniformly to $1$ on $[a,b]$ and by construction $\int_a^b{f \cdot gp_n \circ g}=0$. So $\int_a^b{f}=0$.

Comment: Sorry, but why the first integral is equal to zero??  I don'y understand why $g$ or $g^n$ is equal to $gp_n \circ g$.

Comment: $gp_n\circ g$ is a polynomial in $g$ with non constant term, ie a linear combination of $g^n$ for $n >0$.

Comment: Ok, very smart. Thank you

Comment: Nice answer! So it seems that even if we require the desired equality to hold for  $n\in\mathbb{N}$ instead of $n\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\},$ then still there exists no such non-vanishing function $g$.

Comment: @Perman: we still need $g$ to not vanish. And actually “every $n > 0$“ can be replaced with “every large enough $n$”.